# Autolayout issue on iOS6: "All dependent constraints should have been removed from the engine and also from the view's list of dependent constraints"

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Has anyone encountered this warning message related with autolayout:

```
All dependent constraints should have been removed from the engine and also from the view's list of dependent constraints
```

Currently, we have some footerView with several buttons inside and they are hidden or showed depending on the need. We use full autolayout everywhere. Here's the method for hiding/showing this footerView:

```
- (void)hideFooterView:(BOOL)shouldHide {

  self.containerViewBottomConstraint.constant = shouldHide ? 0 : 50; // expand  containing view to fit to full screen OR make it smaller to fit with footerView

  [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // animate expanding screen height to full height
    [self.footerView setAlpha:(shouldHide ? 0 : 1)];
  } completion:nil];  
}
```

So, when this method is called for the first time then there's no error message. But after the second time mentioned warning appears in console. We can't ignore this warning because in other screens we are encountering crashes with private Apple method calls without any clue how to solve that:

```
[UILayoutContainerView nsis_shouldIntegralizeVariable:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

here's another crash message:

```
[UILayoutContainerView nsis_valueOfVariable:didChangeInEngine:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I was unable to find anything useful related to "nsis_valueOfVariable:didChangeInEngine:" or "Autolayout dependent constraints" keywords on web. Any ideas?

**UPDATE** Commenting out line "[self.view layoutIfNeeded]" seems fixed the issue but  then there will be no animation...

Comment: Are you removing a view that is affected by / involved in constraints? If so, perhaps you should remove those constraints at the same time.

Comment: @matt No, I'm just performing hide/unhide animations.

Comment: Are there any constraints involved with the views that you are hiding?

Comment: @footyapps27 we know there are but that should not matter

Comment: @Centurion I'm going to suggest that you are wrong. We have to explain why it works the first time but not later. It works the first time because your code as shown is fine. It doesn't work later because later, in code that you have not shown, perhaps code that you have forgotten about, you change the constraints or remove a constrained view. This could be the view that `containerViewBottomConstraint` connects to.

Comment: For example you could be messing with `footerView` (if that is view we are constraining to) in some way that you have forgotten about, e.g. replacing it with a different view but you forgot to hook up the constraints to it. Or something.

Comment: But whatever it is, it isn't in this code. It's elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In my project also this issue came. I was getting same warning "All dependent constraints should have been removed from the engine and also from the view's list of dependent constraints".

As you told, when I ignored it and in other screens I got crashes, showing

```
[UILayoutContainerView nsis_shouldIntegralizeVariable:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I found that, in my case I was calling `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` inside `-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`. When I removed this out, the issue was fixed.
No warnings and no crashes.

From this what I understood is, if we call `layoutIfNeeded` just before the view is being deallocated this warning will come. And in next screens it will cause crashing.

It took so much time to figure out this crash. That's why I am sharing my thoughts.

This may help someone.