# All dependent constraints should have been removed from the engine and also from the view's list of dependent constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6

I get the following error when I dismiss the a view controller:

```
All dependent constraints should have been removed from the engine and also from the view's list of dependent constraints
```

Is it because I call `layoutIfNeeded` on the parent `scrollView`?

The app presents a view controller that signs ( with your finger a document ), once the person has finish signing when I ( close ) dismiss the view controller I get the error on iPhone 3GS with iOS6. It works fine on iphone5+ on iOS7. Unfortunately the App has to work on older devices.

Comment: There is a related discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286940/autolayout-issue-on-ios6-all-dependent-constraints-should-have-been-removed-fr and it seems that removing '[self layoutIfNeeded]` sorts the issue but in that way you can't animate constraints. An iOS 6 issue perhaps?

Comment: I need layoutIfNeeded otherwise my controls (view objects) do not display. Also it crashed on this call:     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; if it helps